# How to verify which wireless access point my iOS device is using?

Tags: ios, network, wifi

In my house I have multiple wireless access points, all of which use the same SSID. I'd like to know which wireless AP my iPhone is currently connected to.

On my MacBook I use the [WiFi Explorer](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/wifi-explorer/id494803304?mt=12) app to view available wifi networks and verify which wireless AP the MacBook is currently connected to - the app lists the Vendor name (eg Netgear, TP-Link) beside the SSID.

How can I verify which wireless access point my iOS device is connected to?

The standard iOS Wi-Fi menu only lists the SSID name, and since all APs have the same SSID this doesn't help.

Comment: (the same developer has a [WiFi Explorer for iOS](https://www.adriangranados.com/apps/ios-wifi-explorer) app, but this requires a jailbroken phone)

Comment: I'm assuming you don't want to log into each AP and look at its connection list?

Comment: @Hefewe1zen that's a good workaround, thanks. But ideally I'd prefer to do it from the iOS device

Comment: @Hefewe1zen do you want to put that as an answer - it seems like the best option so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you could log into the admin section for each AP and look at the active connection list.

Comment: sadly (and amazingly) this seems to be the best option

Comment: In the case of the TP Link router, the [TP Link Tether](http://www.tp-link.com/common/Promos/App_Tether.html) software allows you to view the connection status of all devices from the phone, which makes things a bit easier

Answer (score 3):

The Net Analyzer app shows the BSSID which appears to be the same as the access point’s MAC (at least on my network).

https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/network-analyzer/id562315041

Comment: This is a really good answer, you can wander around the house with this app watching it switch APs.